# Type in Google Search Bar using PHP or Alternate?

Tags: php

I know two methods to transfer data in php ,

1. GET POST methods to transfer data (in which you need to own the recieving end as well),
2. customize the url to get the desired result.(in which you DO NOT need to own the recieving end)

Now just wondering, is it possible to type in any form or search bar (like google) through php(preferably) , (like get post methods)... But any other coding is also acceptable

Just clearing that what I want to know. My site opens google.com, and in the search bar Automatically type in the required search words. Thats it. (not even in need to execute the search). Well it would be better if there is execution after an interval of let's say fifteen seconds. But I only wish to see the method to type in the Google bar and thats all

coding or reference will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question:

PHP is a server side scripting language, hence it generally does not interact with the client side. What you can do with PHP is sending the request.

Dealing with server side though is generally done through JavaScript. 
Let me know if you're interested in doing it through JS

Comment: Not a big fan of js. But it may give me the required result so I am interested.

Comment: Just clearing that what I want to know. My site opens google.com,  and in the search bar Automatically type in the required search words. Thats it. (not even in need to execute the search). Well it would be better if there is execution after an interval of let's say fifteen seconds. But I only wish to see the method to type in the Google bar and thats all

Comment: Check this github repo which should have what you're looking for: https://github.com/pykler/lmgtfy